# node + handlebars: dynamically creating and retrieving url path

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

Site `example.com`. A person registers and has a profile `example.com/AndyWarhol`

With most template engines, they want `AndyWarhol.ext` (.hbs with handlebars) as a template to render that page. I'd like to dynamically create the url and display the profile using a template that isn't tied to the url.

2ndary question: what would you call this? (So I can better search for it.)

Comment: I've not encountered where a template engine works like you have described. You set the view in the controller. What's the current project code? Show the routes, the controller that handles the user profile page stuff.

Comment: @Andrius it's not about the info on the resulting page, it's about the url. I need to use and show dynamic urls. In other words, not `example.com/profile` that shows AndyWarhols info, but `example.com/AndyWarhol`. (Do I need to make the OP clearer?)

Comment: So, insert the code that handles that route.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a dynamic content with default template that will have placeholders like `{% username %}` in place of the username (i.e: `AndyWarhol`). To achieve that, you need a controller (the C in MVC) that will take care of fetching the users profiles. It will resemble something akin to `/users/:user` where `:user` is a stand-in for whatever the end user requests. Upon passing `/users/AndyWarhol`, the controller will fetch for user `AndyWarhol` from the DB, and populate the template accordingly.